# How to determine if two cuboids intersect or not (Including contain)

Tags: computational-geometry

Cuboids will not always be aligned with axis. how to determine if they are intersect with each other?

Answer (score 2):

The separating axis theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separating_axis_theorem) ensures that in your case (two cuboids)
there exist a separating plane if they do not intersect. So, the well known approach is to project cuboid vertices (or even the Oriented Bounding Box vertices, without assuming it to be the cube)
to every possible separating axis. There are normals to the cube's faces and the pairwise cross products.

Let N1, N2, N3 be the normals to the first cube's faces and M1, M2, M3 be the normals to the second cube's faces. Let A and B
be the centers of the first and second cube respectively.

Then you have to project every point of the first cube to N1, N2, N3, M1, M2, M3, N1xM1, N1xM2 etc.

Then check the distance between the projected point and the other cube's center.

The full code in C++ (with some obvious operator overloading for vec3 type):

```
bool Intersection_BoxToBox( const Box& ABox, const Box& BBox )
{
    float R, R0, R1;

    eBoxSeparatingAxis SeparatingAxis = S_AXIS_NONE;

    float AxisLen, TmpDepth;

    /// Relative distance
    LVector3 D = BBox.FCenter - ABox.FCenter;

    SeparatingAxis = S_AXIS_NONE;

    /// Test each separating plane with Axes A0..A2, B0..B2 (six cases)

    #define TEST_SEP_PLANE( PARAM_AxisName, PARAM_RelativeVal, PARAM_R0, PARAM_R1, PARAM_Normal ) \
        R  = fabs(PARAM_RelativeVal);       \
        R0 = PARAM_R0;             \
        R1 = PARAM_R1;             \
        /* If (R>R0+R1) Then there is no intersection */\
        TmpDepth = R0 + R1 - R;          \
        if (TmpDepth < 0) return false;         \
                 \
        if (MaxDepth > TmpDepth) {        \
            MaxDepth = TmpDepth;       \
            SeparatingAxis = PARAM_AxisName; \
        }

    float a0 = ABox.FExtent[0];
    float a1 = ABox.FExtent[1];
    float a2 = ABox.FExtent[2];
    float b0 = BBox.FExtent[0];
    float b1 = BBox.FExtent[1];
    float b2 = BBox.FExtent[2];

    /// 1. A0
    float A0D = ABox.FAxis[0].Dot( D );
    float c00 = ABox.FAxis[0].Dot( BBox.FAxis[0] );
    float c01 = ABox.FAxis[0].Dot( BBox.FAxis[1] );
    float c02 = ABox.FAxis[0].Dot( BBox.FAxis[2] );
    TEST_SEP_PLANE( S_AXIS_A0, A0D, a0, b0 * fabs( c00 ) + b1 * fabs( c01 ) + b2 * fabs( c02 ), ABox.FAxis[0] )

    /// 2. A1
    float A1D = D.Dot( ABox.FAxis[1] );
    float c10 = ABox.FAxis[1].Dot( BBox.FAxis[0] );
    float c11 = ABox.FAxis[1].Dot( BBox.FAxis[1] );
    float c12 = ABox.FAxis[1].Dot( BBox.FAxis[2] );
    TEST_SEP_PLANE( S_AXIS_A1, A1D, a1, b0 * fabs( c10 ) + b1 * fabs( c11 ) + b2 * fabs( c12 ), ABox.FAxis[1] )

    /// 3. A2
    float A2D = ABox.FAxis[2].Dot( D );
    float c20 = ABox.FAxis[2].Dot( BBox.FAxis[0] );
    float c21 = ABox.FAxis[2].Dot( BBox.FAxis[1] );
    float c22 = ABox.FAxis[2].Dot( BBox.FAxis[2] );
    TEST_SEP_PLANE( S_AXIS_A2, A2D, a2, b0 * fabs( c20 ) + b1 * fabs( c21 ) + b2 * fabs( c22 ), ABox.FAxis[2] )

    /// 4. B0
    float B0D = BBox.FAxis[0].Dot( D );
    TEST_SEP_PLANE( S_AXIS_B0, B0D, a0 * fabs( c00 ) + a1 * fabs( c01 ) + a2 * fabs( c02 ), b0, BBox.FAxis[0] )

    /// 5. B1
    float B1D = BBox.FAxis[1].Dot( D );
    TEST_SEP_PLANE( S_AXIS_B1, B1D, a0 * fabs( c10 ) + a1 * fabs( c11 ) + a2 * fabs( c12 ), b1, BBox.FAxis[1] )

    /// 6. B2
    float B2D = BBox.FAxis[2].Dot( D );
    TEST_SEP_PLANE( S_AXIS_B2, B2D, a0 * fabs( c20 ) + a1 * fabs( c21 ) + a2 * fabs( c22 ), b2, BBox.FAxis[2] )

    #undef TEST_SEP_PLANE

    /// Now we test the cross-product axes

    #define TEST_SEP_AXIS( PARAM_AxisName, PARAM_DirA, PARAM_DirB, PARAM_RelativeVal, PARAM_R0, PARAM_R1) \
        TempAxis = PARAM_DirA .Cross( PARAM_DirB );     \
        AxisLen  = TempAxis.SqrLength();       \
                    \
        if ( AxisLen > ::Math::EPSILON)           \
        {                    \
            R  = PARAM_RelativeVal;          \
            R0 = PARAM_R0;             \
            R1 = PARAM_R1;             \
                    \
            TmpDepth = R0 + R1 - fabs(R);       \
            if (TmpDepth < 0) return false;         \
                    \
            if (MaxDepth * AxisLen > TmpDepth )     \
            {                 \
                MaxDepth = TmpDepth / AxisLen;      \
                SeparatingAxis = PARAM_AxisName; \
            }                 \
        }

    ///  7.-15.       Name        DirA            DirB                RelVal                      R0                           R1
    TEST_SEP_AXIS( S_AXIS_A0B0, ABox.FAxis[0], BBox.FAxis[0] , c10 * A2D - c20 * A1D,  a1 * fabs( c20 ) + a2 * fabs( c10 ), b1 * fabs( c02 ) + b2 * fabs( c01 ) )
    TEST_SEP_AXIS( S_AXIS_A0B1, ABox.FAxis[0], BBox.FAxis[1] , c11 * A2D - c21 * A1D,  a1 * fabs( c21 ) + a2 * fabs( c11 ), b0 * fabs( c02 ) + b2 * fabs( c00 ) )
    TEST_SEP_AXIS( S_AXIS_A0B2, ABox.FAxis[0], BBox.FAxis[2] , c12 * A2D - c22 * A1D,  a1 * fabs( c22 ) + a2 * fabs( c12 ), b0 * fabs( c01 ) + b1 * fabs( c00 ) )
    TEST_SEP_AXIS( S_AXIS_A1B0, ABox.FAxis[1], BBox.FAxis[0] , c20 * A0D - c00 * A2D,  a0 * fabs( c20 ) + a2 * fabs( c00 ), b1 * fabs( c12 ) + b2 * fabs( c11 ) )
    TEST_SEP_AXIS( S_AXIS_A1B1, ABox.FAxis[1], BBox.FAxis[1] , c21 * A0D - c01 * A2D,  a0 * fabs( c21 ) + a2 * fabs( c01 ), b0 * fabs( c12 ) + b2 * fabs( c10 ) )
    TEST_SEP_AXIS( S_AXIS_A1B2, ABox.FAxis[1], BBox.FAxis[2] , c22 * A0D - c02 * A2D,  a0 * fabs( c22 ) + a2 * fabs( c02 ), b0 * fabs( c11 ) + b1 * fabs( c10 ) )
    TEST_SEP_AXIS( S_AXIS_A2B0, ABox.FAxis[2], BBox.FAxis[0] , c00 * A1D - c10 * A0D,  a0 * fabs( c10 ) + a1 * fabs( c00 ), b1 * fabs( c22 ) + b2 * fabs( c21 ) )
    TEST_SEP_AXIS( S_AXIS_A2B1, ABox.FAxis[2], BBox.FAxis[1] , c01 * A1D - c11 * A0D,  a0 * fabs( c11 ) + a1 * fabs( c01 ), b0 * fabs( c22 ) + b2 * fabs( c20 ) )
    TEST_SEP_AXIS( S_AXIS_A2B2, ABox.FAxis[2], BBox.FAxis[2] , c02 * A1D - c12 * A0D,  a0 * fabs( c12 ) + a1 * fabs( c02 ), b0 * fabs( c21 ) + b1 * fabs( c20 ) )

    if ( SeparatingAxis == S_AXIS_NONE ) { return false; }

    #undef TEST_SEP_AXIS

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first determine the orientation of one of the cuboids. Then transform the coordinates of the other(s) into that coordinate system. You also have the measure of the first cuboid to easily set up conditions for a point beeing left/inside/right of the cuboid in each axis.

It now will be easy to check whether

- a vertice is inside the cuboid, i.e. the coordinates in all three dimensions are inside => intersecting or containing
- an edge (represented by two vertices) intersects a face of the cuboid. You don't have to check that when the two belonging vertices are on the same side (left and left or right and right) of the cuboid.

If every coordinate-pair (in every dimension) of every vertice-pair is around (left and right or right and left) the cuboid, is is contained (instead of containing).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm Viktor Latypov's answer. I implemented the solution in my [Skyrim mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/67473) and all works fine.

The only exception is that 4--6 (with testing B0, B1 and B3 axes) cases has a bug.

Instead we should use:

```
TEST_SEP_PLANE(B0D, a0 * fabs(c00) + a1 * fabs(c10) + a2 * fabs(c20), b0);
TEST_SEP_PLANE(B1D, a0 * fabs(c01) + a1 * fabs(c11) + a2 * fabs(c21), b1);
TEST_SEP_PLANE(B2D, a0 * fabs(c02) + a1 * fabs(c12) + a2 * fabs(c22), b2);
```

This is because in those cases we should project three ABox's normals to BBox's i-th normal (for each case, for i = 0..2). The origin code does different thing -- it still projects BBox's normals to ABox's. Likely this is due to copy-paste error from cases 1--3.